# C#: create a do-nothing Action on class instantiation

Tags: c#, delegates, action, lambda

I have a class that the user can pass an Action into (or not).

```
public class FooClass<T> : BaseClass<T>
{
    public FooClass()
        : this((o) => ()) //This doesn't work...
    {
    }

    public FooClass(Action<T> myAction)
        : base(myAction)
    {
    }
}
```

---

Basically, I can't pass null into my base class for the `Action`. But, at the same time I don't want to force my user to pass in an `Action`. Instead, I want to be able to create a "do-nothing" action on the fly.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You want to say

```
this(t => { })
```

Think of it like this. You need `t => anonymous-expression-body`. In this case, `anonymous-expression-body` is an `expression` or a `block`. You can't have an empty expression so you can't indicate an empty method body with an `expression`. Therefore, you have to use a `block` in which case you can say `{ }` to indicate the a `block` has an empty `statement-list` and is therefore the empty body.

For details, see the grammar specification, appendix B.

And here's another way to think of it, which is a way that you could use to discover this for yourself. An `Action<T>` is a method that takes in a `T` and returns `void`. You can define an `Action<T>` via an non-anonymous method or via an anonymous method. You are trying to figure out how to do it using an anonymous method (or rather, a very special anonymous method, namely a lambda expression). If you wanted to do this via a non-anonymous method you would say

```
private void MyAction<T>(T t) { }
```

and then you could say

```
this(MyAction)
```

which uses the concept of a method group. But now you want to translate this to a lambda expression. So, let's just take that method body and make it a lambda expression. Therefore, we throw away the `private void MyAction<T>(T t)` and replace it with `t =>` and copy verbatim the method body `{ }`.

```
this(t => { })
```

Boom.

Answer (score 7):

Shouldn't it be curly brackets?

```
public FooClass()
        : this(o => {})
    {
    }
```

Lambda form is `(/*paramaters*/) => {/*body*}`

Parenthesis around the parameters can be omitted, but Curly braces around the body can be omitted only if it's a single (not empty) statement.